# VM's migrating to other host on the cluster getting request time out on the other host

Tags: vmware

We are new to VMware HA and DRS. We have a cluster in which we have 6 physical host. When a vm is migrating from one physical host to other due to DRS, its not getting up ang giving Request time out. After that we have to manually bring it up by changing VLAN's.

Please help if anyone knows the solutions.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

While migrating the VM from one host to another host the VM will be stunned for few seconds and you will find RTO.During the migration phase of VM,we will have three phase first is verifying the connectivity between source and destination host,then copy of the VM memory bitmap to destination host,register the VM to destination host and notify network device using RARP.

In most of the case the port group name and vLAN are not unique across the hosts in cluster and vLAN not allowed to the host.